# Aligned equation number in content section

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, equations

I try to figure out how I can align the number of the equation in my content section.

I am using this code to add a 'List of Equations sections' :

```
    %For list of equations
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{\Large List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}
```

but I doesn't align with the previous sections :

[image]

How can I change that ?

Thank you very much,

Regards,

-U

Comment: Welcome. You should add a complete MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was lying in the new command and to get rid of it just apply a new command parameter like **\hspace** :

```
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{\Large List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\hspace*{1.5em}\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}
```

It works fine for me :

[image]